# How can I get an image or link to show up in an Oracle APEX Interactive Report?

Tags: html, image, hyperlink, oracle-apex

I have recently started attempting to develop a web application in Oracle APEX and have come across some issues that have stumped me. Namely having HTML strings stored in the database be parsed as HTML and not simply displayed as text...

In my database (which I imported from an Excel spreadsheet, which I had exported from my department's Access database) I have two columns: Icon and Link. Icon contains an HTML string, `<img src="images/icon.png">`, which denotes what the status of the document in that row is. Link contains another HTML string, `<a href="link.html">LINK</a>`, which is unique for each row and links to an exterior HTML page with further information. This database had previously been being exported weekly and converted to HTML manually and put online for upper management to view the status of the documents my team is working on.

When I heard about APEX I was excited because it looked like it would be a good replacement for our Access database and static HTML reports and forms. I still think that it will be but there are some quirks that I need help figuring out, namely how to have my HTML strings be parsed and displayed instead of just outputed as text.

Any thoughts? I am relevtively new to APEX but I know SQL. Please be as clear and detailed as you can, Thanks!

Comment: I think is only possible to load images that are upload to your apex application.

Comment: The OP says the image is an exterior HTML page; and `<img src="http.example.com/cat.jpg" />` would render if generated as noted in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the Display Type of the column is "Standard Report Column":
[image]

This Display Type renders the HTML; some other Display Types escape it.

Comment: No wonder I could not find documentation... its freaking obvious! I could have sworn I tried that, thank you! Worked like a charm! I would also like to link to another answer that helped me solve part of this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917/remove-quotes-and-commas-from-a-string-in-mysql . That question helped me clean up the strings that SQL messed with so the images could display correctly once I got the column properly set up. Thanks everyone!